# Collapsing Tiered Proportions in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a data set that has cumulative sums for each subsection and I would like to collapse it down so the sums reflect only the amount for the base level.  For example, my current data set looks like this:

```
Bac prot Deltaprot Desulf Desulfacaea Desulfovibrio   0.156%
Bac prot Deltaprot Desulf Desulfacaea Bilophila       0.171%
Bac prot Deltaprot Desulf Desulfacaea                 0.391%
Bac prot Deltaprot Desulf uncl_Desulf                 1.922%
Bac prot Deltaprot Desulf                             2.311%
Bac prot Deltaprot                                    2.333%
Bac prot                                              2.517%
```

If you notice, the percentages "stack". So the percentage of Desulfovibrio is included in the overall percentage of Bac prot.

I want to seperate this down, and anything that isn't included in the base ranking would take on a category of "unclassified_".

So for example, the entry of Desulfacaea that is not further subsetted would need to be changed to a subset of unclassified_Desulfacaea with a percentage of 0.391%-(0.156%+0.171%) or 0.064%.

Does anyone know of an easier way to do this than writing for loops?